# Formula returning multiple info and going to new row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a formula, have no idea where to start, that will bring back multi cell information, based on if one cell has a "x."
[image: Data Source]

Using the spreadsheet attached, I need the information in Start Date, Full Name, and EEID to be return to a new spreadsheet if the cell A (before the date) has a X in it. It then needs to put the next line with a X on the next available line on the new spreadsheet.  Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using `FILTER` yet?

Comment: I have looked at it, but I probably just above a novice in Excel and wasn't having much success.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 current channel you can use this formula:

`=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:I100,A2:A100="x"),2,7,9)`

Assuming that your table starts in A1

UPDATE - avoid using `CHOOSECOLS`

```
=LET(v,FILTER(A2:I100,A2:A100="x"),
INDEX(v,SEQUENCE(ROWS(v)),{2,7,9}))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am receiving a #NAME? error

Comment: Then you don't have Excel 365 current channel ... updated the answer - using only formulas you should have.

Comment: I am currently on semi-annual channel through my employer

Comment: The the updated version should work

Comment: The new formula is also giving a #NAME? error.  Really do appreciate the help.

Comment: What is your language?